# Python unittest execute code per-suite/class in a hierarchy?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have some unittests with expensive setup work. I'd like to group them and perform this initialization only once for a given group of tests. I've looked at `setUpClass` but it doesn't work in a hiearchy. I have many tests derived from the same base test, and they would end up sharing state using the class methods.

For example, I have this hieararchy of test cases:

```
TreeBase 
  <- PineTests
  <- NeedleTests
  <- ConeTests
```

The family of `TreeBase` tests all share an expensive initialization. It must however be done for each derived class on its own (the state is unique to the most derived TestCase). So what I want is a flow like this:

1. Call PineTests::setup
2. Call PineTests tests
3. Call PineTests::teardown
4. Repeat for NeedleTests, ConeTests

Comment: can you share your work setup?

Answer (score 0):

Modules can be used as test suites. Group test functions into modules and use the `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule` functions. It isn't exactly the file structure I'd like, but it does work.

Classes deriving from `TestCase` can still be used in this setup, you don't need to revert to using plain functions. It's better to keep the common functionality inside a global helper class though. This way you don't need to rely on `unittest` much.